# Linq to get row with a minimum value of a column but based on another column value

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5, min

I have seen related questions and answer but none of those helped me.
I have created a linq query to get an IEnumerable list like this -

```
**price**     **car_name**    **location**
  23              carA          locationA
  43              carA          locationB
  56              carA          locationC
  12              carB          locationA
  34              carB          locationB
  46              carB          locationC
```

Now I want only rows with minimum price of each car...
Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Sorry I wasn't clear about my question but I want all the location too...I show that in a separate dropdown list.

Comment: Could you share any existing code?

Comment: Regarding your edit: two of the provided answers already include the location (in the Car object). Since you haven't shared any of your existing code, we can only guess how to help you put the locations in a dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Group the Collection based on Car Name and then Order each group by price so that you can the minimum.

```
var result = carList.GroupBy(x=>x.Name)
                     .Select(x=>x.OrderBy(p=>p.Price).First());
```

If you want to avoid the Order By, you could make use of Aggregate.

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Select(g => g.Aggregate((c1, c2) => c1.Price < c2.Price ? c1 : c2));
```

Aggregate would iterate only one time over the collection, keeping track of the car with minimum price.

In either case, output sample,

[image]

Comment: I want all the locations too...I have to show that in a dropdownlist.

Comment: To get all the locations, you can use carList.Select(x=>x.Location).Distinct()

Answer (score 0):

```
from cs in myContext.CarStore
group cs by cs.car_name into cgroup
 select new {
        Car_Name= cgroup.Key,
        Price= cgroup.Min(cs=> cs.price)});
```

i think this may help..

Answer (score 0):

Others came up with the idea to group your cars into groups with same CarName. Then they order all CarPrices in each group, after which they take the FirstOrDefault CarPrice.

It is a bit of a waste to Order all CarPrices if you only want the minimum CarPrice

For this I use the [GroupBy overload with KeySelector, ElementSelector and ResultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__)

```
var cheapestCars = allCars.GroupBy(

    // key selector:
    car => car.CarName,

    // element selector
    car => car.CarPrice,

    // result selector:
    (carName, pricesOfCarsWithThisCarName) => new
    {
        CarName = carName,
        LowestAvailablePrices = pricesOfCarsWithThisCarName.Min(),
    });
```

Comment: `OrderBy().First()` only enumerates the cars once, just like your code.

Comment: Interesting. If I look at the reference source for queryable orderby (google for it, I don't know how to add a link in a comment), it will do a QuickSort when you ask for the first element. Whis QuickSort will sort all elements, even though you ask only the first one.So even after you found the smallest one, the smallest-but-one and the smallest-but-two are also compared

Comment: You can test it to find that it evaluates each item only once.